# Prevent serverless from autocreatin API endpoint

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

When deploying my project with `serverless` it automatically creates endpoint for all known functions. I want to have number of functions without API endpoint i.e. to call it using `AWS.Lambda().invoke(lambda_name, params)`.

Is it possible to instruct `serverless` do not create endpoint for specific functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `serverless.yml` looks similar to this:

```
functions:
  foo:
    handler: handler.foo
    events:
      - http:
          path: foo
          method: POST
```

Just remove the `events` part:

```
functions:
  foo:
    handler: handler.foo
```